# C# attribute naming

Tags: c#

Does the C# compiler identify inherited Attribute classes to check if they contain the word 'Attribute'?
In the below example, [Blah], [BlahA], and [BlahAttribute] are available attributes

```cs
    [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method, AllowMultiple=true)]
    public class BlahA: Attribute
    {
        //stuff
    }

    [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method, AllowMultiple=true)]
    public class BlahAttribute: Attribute
    {
        //stuff
    }

    //acceptable
    [BlahA]
    [Blah]
    [BlahAttribute]
```

Comment: When resolving `[Foo]`, the compiler indeed looks first for a type named `Foo`, and if that doesn't resolve: it looks for `FooAttribute`. Is that what you're asking?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The specification is rather clear on this:

> A class that derives from the abstract class System.Attribute, whether directly or indirectly, is an attribute class. The declaration of an attribute class defines a new kind of attribute that can be placed on a declaration. By convention, attribute classes are named with a suffix of Attribute. **Uses of an attribute may either include or omit this suffix.**

Further down under Attribute specification:

> By convention, attribute classes are named with a suffix of `Attribute`. An *attribute_name* of the form *type_name* may either include or omit this suffix. If an attribute class is found both with and without this suffix, an ambiguity is present, and a compile-time error results. If the *attribute_name* is spelled such that its right-most identifier is a verbatim identifier (...), then only an attribute without a suffix is matched, thus enabling such an ambiguity to be resolved.

([source](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/blob/master/spec/attributes.md))

Since the spec allows users to either include or omit this suffix, the C# compiler also allows both. In your case, `[BlahA]` refers to `BlahA`, while `[Blah]` and `[BlahAttribute]` refer to `BlahAttribute`. If you defined an attribute with the name `Blah`,`[Blah]` would be ambiguous and you'd have to resolve it either by specifying `[BlahAttribute]` or using the verbatim identifier `[@Blah]`.

UPDATE:

I was lurking through Roslyn's source and completely by accident I stumbled upon the bits responsible for this part of the spec. You can find them in [Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Binder.Binder_Lookup](http://sourceroslyn.io/#Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp/Binder/Binder_Lookup.cs,407) (at least as of 2020-05-19). It so happens that a rather interesting edge-case is described there. When resolving the attribute's type they look for `Foo` and `FooAttribute` as mentioned above. If only one of them is viable they choose that one, if both are then an ambiguity is reported. BUT if one of them is viable and the other is ambiguous itself, they generously choose the single viable option. To illustrate this, consider:

```
namespace A
{
    class FooAttribute : System.Attribute
    {

    }
}

namespace B
{
    class FooAttribute : System.Attribute
    {
    }
}

namespace C
{
    class Foo : System.Attribute
    {
    }
}

namespace D
{
    using A;
    using B;
    using C;

    [Foo] // Attribute resolution.
    class Bar 
    {
    }
}
```

The candidates for attribute resolution are `A.FooAttribute` and `B.FooAttribute` when looking with the `Attribute` suffix, as well as `C.Foo` when looking without it. The first choice is ambiguous - the compiler wouldn't be able to decide between `A`'s and `B`'s version - so `C.Foo` is chosen and the above code compiles. Now remove either of the `using A` or `using B` directives. Suddenly, only one `FooAttribute` is a viable candidate and there is an ambiguity between it and `C.Foo`. [Try it](https://dotnetfiddle.net/4E5lAg)!

Comment: Also to add if you want the actual method that tries to resolve the type of the attribute, here it is.

https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/master/mcs/mcs/attribute.cs#L298

Comment: @JamesMallon that is Mono source which isn't the best documentation source these days.  https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/mscorlib/system/attribute.cs

Comment: And the interface is defined here: https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/3b1eaf5203992df69de44c783a3eda37d3d4cd10/mscorlib/system/cominterfaces.cs#L41

Comment: @DavidL James' source was for the compiler's bit responsible for implementing this part of the spec. I'm not familiar with Roslyn's source enough to find the respective bit there, but that's probably what you would want to substitute in place of the Mono compiler.

For the record, referencesource is also not the best documentation source since everything moved to `dotnet/runtime`.

Comment: @V0ldek dotnet/runtime is specifically for .net core which could be applicable but isn’t referenced. But yes, good callout, that is probably the best reference source going forward.

Comment: Thank you! I asked because the compiler only seems to recognize issues with attribute naming during the build process and not during text editing.

Comment: @JamesMallon
I found the Roslyn's implementation of this part of the C# spec and an interesting edge case alongside it. Thought I'd share it in an update to the answer!