# Live password registration validation using Annotation

Tags: c#, view, model, controller

I'm trying to stack the annotation for validation using custom ones, but it ignores it

```
[RegularExpression(@"^(?=.*\W).*$", ErrorMessage = "Password must contain at least 1 special character.")]
[Validation(ErrorMessage = "Password must contain at least 1 uppercase letter.")]
//[PasswordComplexity(ErrorMessage = "Password must contain at least 1 lower letter.")]
public string Password { get; set; }
```

The custom annotation is just like any other annotation,

```
public class Validation : ValidationAttribute
{
    public override bool IsValid(object value)
    {
        var password = (string)value;

        bool _hasUppercase = hasUpperCase(password);

        if (!_hasUppercase)
        {
            ErrorMessage = "Password must contain at least one uppercase letter.";
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }

    private bool hasUpperCase(string password)
    {
        return Regex.IsMatch(password, @"[A-Z]");
    }
}
```

But it did work before, and then i tried to add another one, suddenly the first one doesnt work and everything doesnt. Except the RegularExpression annotation attr, I'm still a beginner so I don't know how to debug this kind of problems, and i can't put any breakpoints or try to see anything. Can someone help on this one. Or atleast please give me a link of useful ones, that has stack annotations for live validation.

Comment: Have a hard time understanding what you are trying to say, sorry. for example: `But it did work before...` okay, but how should we know what you mean with "before", we have no context what was before what was after. `i tried to add another one` another one what? and so on... its really hard to understand without any context.

Comment: FYI: `Validation : ValidationAttribute` this is a bad idea - attributes are special and the word "Attribute" can be ommited when using them because the are all attributes when used as an attribute - consider naming your attribute differently.

Comment: see for example this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60477874

Comment: thanks for the help, yeah it was very bad idea, it took me time to understood attribute, but yeah I fix it with javascript. So it's ok right now